# String not loading into STRUCT correctly

Tags: c#, .net, struct

For brevity and clarity the struct and variables have been shortened and renamed.

A BinaryReader is used to populate the following struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 59, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct TheStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string MyFirstString;

    public int MyInt;

    public short MyShort;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
    public string MyNextString;

    public byte MyByte;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string MyLastString;

    public double MyDouble;
}
```

After reading in the data, all variables contain the correct information except the first member MyFirstString.
MyFirstString contains only the first three characters of the four characters that were read.

What is causing this and how do correct it?

Thanks to all who have posted struct examples in the past, they have been a great help to get me this far, but I can't seem to find anything that addresses this issue exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is zero terminated, so only `SizeConst - 1` characters will be placed in the struct, followed by the terminator character.

You can use a character array to get all characters:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
public char[] MyFirstString;
```